# QWidget/QFrame not showing background or border when added to layout

Tags: qt

I have a QFrame derived object:

```
class SubjectLineDisplay : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    // Members

public:
    explicit SubjectLineDisplay(const QString&, const QString&, quint32, QWidget *parent = 0);
};
```

In the constructor, I set a background for it and a border:

```
QPalette p(palette());
p.setColor(QPalette::Background, QColor(255, 255, 255));
setPalette(p);
setLayout(mainLayout); // The mainLayout is a VBoxLayout which is a collection of a few QLabels
setFixedHeight(lTitle->size().height() + lId->size().height());
```

When i do this in `main()`:

```
SubjectLineDisplay* x = new SubjectLineDisplay("NETWORK", "Network Centric Programming", 4);
x->show();
```

The widget shows up in a window, with the background and frame displaying properly, just as I would want. However, when I add it to another layout to show it:

```
SubjectLineDisplay* lineDisplay = new SubjectLineDisplay(
            subjectNameLE->text(), idLE->text(), creditSpin->value()
);

emit newSubjectAdded(Course(subjectNameLE->text(), idLE->text(), creditSpin->value()));

subjectNameLE->clear();
creditSpin->setValue(3);
idLE->clear();

subjectLineLayout->addWidget(lineDisplay); //Adding the widget to a layout
```

Now, I don't see the frame or the border. How do I get the layout to display the frame and the border? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Could you try using setAutoFillBackground(true)?
For as far as I'm aware foregrounds are always drawn, but backgrounds are not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. My background does show up now, but I still can't see any borders for the QFrame. And I cant see the borders only when I add the widget to the layout. When I just instantiate an object of the QFrame-derived object and call `show` on it, it displays a border.

Comment: Spent much more time than i expected to find this simple line!